# Dim(Fade out) Border when button(parent) is disabled

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a Button template which contains a border around a grid. 
When the button is disabled, the border still appears active. 
Is there a way I can fade out the border when button is disabled and show border when button is enabled?

```
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Border BorderThickness="{Binding Path=BorderThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
            AncestorType=Button}}" BorderBrush="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" 
                Opacity="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}">
```

[Buttons with drop menu are mine, the others are typical buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RucM0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a trigger.  Here I made the border green when disabled.

```
    <Button Content="test" Name="test" Height="20">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="{Binding Path=BorderThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
        AncestorType=Button}}" BorderBrush="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" 
            Opacity="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}">
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm. I tried to do a trigger but I tried to add it to the border itself and not the control template. Big help!